# Occasional Crunch/Grinding noise when shifting into first gear at speed

Tags: shifting, gears, transmission

When I am doing about 30-20mph, and am about to stop at a junction, where I know I will have to stop, I shift my car into first gear

However, sometimes when I do this, it makes a quick gear grinding noise when I shift. It lasts for about 1/2 a second.

What is this? Am I destroying my gearbox by doing this?

**EDIT: I keep the clutch down until I am stopped! I don't shift into 1st at 30!**

**I'm not asking why my engine is exploding! ;)**

Comment: Never downshift to 1st. 2nd is the lowest you should go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are down shifting you are using the [engine as a brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_braking), however if you are down-shifting at very high RPM and your engine is revving, over time the [synchronizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_transmission) can be damaged, or it is already damaged.

Thus, to prevent further damage just use only your brake, if you can.

> Note: when I was taking my C category driving lessons, they told us that in the most cases when the vehicle is empty and/or on horizontal plane, we should always use the second gear to start motion. First gear is only kept for full load and inclined plane.

### Addition after the question edit:

In that case you probably need clutch adjustment or change of clutch disk.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I kept the clutch down. I don't shift into 1st from 30!